# How do you convert a page to pdf and include an asset download link in markdown?

Tags: pdf, markdown, mkdocs

I have tried with different plugins listed on here: https://github.com/mkdocs/mkdocs/wiki/MkDocs-Plugins#pdf--site-conversion

But all of them always gives me the same error

`AttributeError: module 'mkdocs.utils' has no attribute 'string_types'`

My SO is windows 10, so I had some issues getting the Cairo library that is needed. But even in a container that we use to deploy the page gives the same error.

Comment: maybe have a look at https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#creating-a-pdf

Comment: It would appear that that plugin has not been updated for the most recent version of MkDocs. I would suggest raising an issue with the developers of the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Update plugins to most recent versions in requirements.txt.

For example:

```
mkdocs>=1.1.2
```

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of problems with `mkdocs` on different platforms and installations I switched completely to docker. Instead of a default image I made my own special docker image [alinex/mkdocs](https://hub.docker.com/repository/docker/alinex/mkdocs). Find the sources at [GitLab](https://gitlab.com/alinex/docker-mkdocs) from which it is build. I checked that it can be used locally to build the documentation or within a build step.

So you only need to run the following command within your mkdocs directory:

```sh
docker run -v $(pwd):/data alinex/mkdocs
```

A description of what is included as modules can be find with examples at http://alinex.gitlab.io/env/mkdocs.

Maybe I can help someone with this, too.